# Is the story about Archimedes a myth?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/myth)

> myth: an ancient story or set of stories, especially explaining the early history of a group of people or about natural events and facts

With the definition, a myth doesn't have to involve a god like Thor, Prometheus or Athena.

So, is the story about Archimedes of Syracuse a myth? If not. Is there a noun to refer to this kind of story which is about someone who lived long time ago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Myth** has a strong implication of not being true. It can refer to commonly held incorrect beliefs about modern things or to the kind of stories your definition is referencing--large scope stories that purport to explain the origin of the world/humanity/why animals have particular features, etc.

There may well be stories about Archimedes that aren't true--though since we know he was a real person we'd probably call them **[apocryphal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apocryphal)**, rather than "myths." Without knowing what story you're referring to, it's difficult to say whether a particular story about him is true or false.

A true story about Archimedes could be called a biography or history or account.

Answer (score -1):

A quick explanation:

A myth concerns fictional beings, such as gods.

A legend is a story which, while itself may not be completely factual, concerns people who actually existed.

So stories of Archimedes would not be myths, but may well be legends.

Comment: A myth is not just about fictional beings, as is evidenced from the definition given in the question.

Comment: Okay, perhaps, but the point is that myths are not about verifiably once-existing known-by-name people either.

Comment: @PrimeMover They very much are, I believe. I just put **asquith story is a myth** into a search engine and found https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/11193714/Meet-Margot-Asquith-aprime-ministers-wife-who-was-more-vilified-than-Cherie....html which mentions several 'myths' about Margot Asquith, who certainly existed. The Telegraph is still known as a quality newspaper (at least in its level of writing).

Comment: Myths can be about real people. Choose any relatively famous person (say Paul McCartney) and Google "the myth that Paul McCartney"). You'll probably get dozens or hundreds of hits.

Comment: People use words all the time inappropriately. Just because you've googled some old rubbish about some dopey old has-been doesn't mean the words are being used correctly therein.

Comment: @simonatrcl The telegraph is still a newspaper. However "quality" they may be, they all contribute to the deterioration of the English language.